# How to close brakets in php $_SESSION?

Tags: php, html, session

when i use first code it works  but not working for second one.

first code that works fine

```html
<?php 
session_start();
 

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email'])){

//if not logged in
header ("location: login.php");


}

else {
?>

welcome page 


<?php } >
```

But when i try to do this only "if" statement is working "else" is showing nothing

```html
<?PHP

session_start();

  

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email'])){ 

?>

html codes here  (works fine )


<?php}  


else { ?>
diffrent html codes here 
(but this  section is not working) 

<?php }?>
```

what is wrong and how should i close "{} "  in this case ...please help

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Jannatul!**

In your second PHP opening tag, you have this:

```
<?php}
```

This without a space may be causing issues while parsing your code. Try and replacing it to this:

```
<?php }
```

If this works please tell me so, and if it doesn't I will gladly be willing to assist you further.
**Matt**

Comment: No problem! Please upvote it as the correct answer so I get credit!

Answer (score 0):

Try this without that mess..

```
<?php 

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_email']))
{ 
echo 'html codes here  (works fine )';
}  
else 
{ 
echo 'diffrent html codes here (but this  section is not working) - but maybe now does';
}
?>
```